# Having an Intent go to a layout in my main xml file

Tags: android, variables, android-activity, android-intent

Anyone know how to use an intent to display the view of one of my child layouts in my parent xml layout?  I am using ViewFlipper and want a button to be clicked to display a specific view in my xml file:

IE, something like this:

```
    case R.id.previous_box:

            Intent j = new Intent(mFlipper.setDisplayedChild(3));
            startActivity(j);
            return;
```

Or something like that - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not approaching it the right way. An intent is not related to layouts. An intent is related to activities. You'll either need to create an activity for each sub-layout, or you need to specify in the intent (via data or extras) which layout to use.

In your case, you could specify the layout in an extra, and you'll read that in onCreate of your activity and set the appropriate layout.